# How to overlay GUI over 3D scene in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, 3d, javafx-3d

I have a 3D scene in JavaFX and need to overlay GUI over the 3D scene. I have tried adding buttons and text to the scene but they always appear in the 3d view as 3D objects. I have looked around and haven't found how to do it. The only workaround would be creating a whole new window and putting the settings there but that isn't an option in this case. Thanks for the help!!

Something like this
[image]
Or this
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution for what you are looking for is the `SubScene`, a built-in JavaFX [container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/SubScene.html):

> The SubScene class is the container for content in a scene graph. SubScene provides separation of different parts of a scene, each of which can be rendered with a different camera, depth buffer, or scene anti-aliasing. A SubScene is embedded into the main scene or another sub-scene.

If you have a look at the [3DViewer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u-dev/rt/file/c3f242e6146c/apps/samples/3DViewer) project, you'll find it is like the pictures you have posted:

[image: 3DViewer]

You can find a small sample of how to add a subScene to a regular scene in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628702/javafx-2d-part-in-3d-application/28629048#28629048).