# Static 2D text over 3D scene in javafx java

Tags: javafx-8, javafx-3d

My goal is to overlay 2D text over a 3d scene in javafx as seen in [image: this image]

Using a subscene is not a valid choice as I want the 3d model to be able to take up the entire space on the screen.

I tried adding a label to the scene and turning depth buffering off but once the model gets rotated (the actual camera changes position) the correct positioning breaks. (Used code to control the [camera](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/graphics-tutorial/sampleapp3d-code.htm#CJAFJADF) )

Can I somehow overlay a static 2D GUI over my 3D scene maybe by using anchor panes and having a 2D scene with transparent background?

On stack overflow I only found these questions:
[Question No.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38164068/how-to-overlay-gui-over-3d-scene-in-javafx)
[Question No.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28753724/javafx-2d-text-with-background-in-3d-scene)
which don't correspond to my exact needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I misunderstood the concept of subscenes as they all showed entirely separated controls. Overlaying 3D Text is possible using the following structure...

- Root Container (e.g. an Anchor Pane)

  - 2D Content (Label)
  - SubScene

    - perspective camera
    - root 3D

      - 3D content

Code example:

```
//Add 2D content here
AnchorPane globalRoot = new AnchorPane();
globalRoot.getChildren().add(new Label("Hello World"));
Scene scene = new Scene(globalRoot, 1024, 768, true);

SubScene sub = new 
SubScene(root3D,1024,768,false,SceneAntialiasing.BALANCED);
sub.setCamera(camera);
globalRoot.getChildren().add(sub);

//Add all 3D content to the root3D node    

primaryStage.setScene(scene);
primaryStage.show();
```